# can i continue an id i created using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Got some errors here. I am trying to use an id which I created using javascript but it won't work.

```
$('#button').on('click', function() {
    $('#here').html('<p> thank you for clicking </p>');
    $('#here2').html('<input type="button" id="button2" value="click me now" />');
});
$('#button2').on('mouseover' function() {
    $('#button2').css({
        'background-color':'#0FF';
        'width':'400px';
        'height':'200px';
    });
});
```

I think that it is possible but I don't know how.
Please teach me the right way.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Event binding on dynamically created elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jquery event validation: Because then DOM was ready, button2 id was not there. So it can be caught like this:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','#button2', function() {  // See change in this line.
    $('#button2').css({
        'background-color':'#0FF',
        'width':'400px',
        'height':'200px'
    });
});
```

Comment: You'll need to use commas after each style property, rather than semi-colons. This will give you a syntax error otherwise.